# ISE when accessing methods on DMLException in batch context

Tags: apex, batch, gack

I'm receiving an Internal Salesforce.com Error when attempting to access methods of a DMLException in a batch class.

```
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    private String query;
    private List<Exception> errors;

    public MyBatch(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
        try {
            // some operation on scope throws a DmlException
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.errors.add(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        String message = '';
        for (Exception e : this.errors) {
            message += String.format('TYPE: {0}, MESSAGE: {1}<br/>',
                new List<String>{
                    e.getTypeName(),
                    e.getMessage()
                }
            );
            for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
                message += String.format('DML TYPE: {0}, DML MESSAGE: {1}',
                    new List<Object> {
                        e.getDmlType(i), // ISE here
                        e.getDmlMessage(i)
                    }
                );
            }
        }
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setHtmlBody(message);
        // ....
    }

}
```

`e.getDmlType(i)` is the last method call before the error.
I've also tried with `getDmlMessage(i)` and `getDmlFieldNames(i)`, so far all are ending up with an ISE.

[image]

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to do with the serialization of the stateful property `List<Exception>`.

Although the `Exception` class is generally serializable, some of its subclasses are not. (you could say there are *exceptions* to this) DmlException being one of them. (EmailException is also).

Try these in the dev console, to see what I mean.

`JSON.serialize(new IllegalArgumentException());`

vs.

`JSON.serialize(new DmlException());`

To achieve the desired result I built up the email message on each exception and stored that instead.

```
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {

    private String query;
    private String emailBody;

    public MyBatch(String query) {
        this.query = query;
        this.emailBody = '';
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
    }
    
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<SObject> scope) {
        try {
            // some operation on scope
        } catch (Exception e) {
            addError(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    
    public void addError(Exception e) {
        this.emailBody += String.format('TYPE: {0}, MESSAGE: {1}<br/>',
            new List<String>{
                e.getTypeName(),
                e.getMessage()
            }
        );
        if (e instanceof DmlException) {
            for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
                this.emailBody += String.format('DML TYPE: {0}, DML MESSAGE: {1}',
                    new List<Object> {
                        e.getDmlType(i),
                        e.getDmlMessage(i)
                    }
                );
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setHtmlBody(this.emailBody);
        // ....
    }

}
```